# NodeJS, ParseServer, kue-scheduler job called multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-server

I'm using ParseServer(`v2.2.16`), kue-sheduler(`v0.6.0`) and NodeJS(`v6.3.0`), I'm using this format to queue a job each day at 12:00pm:

```
Queue.every('00 00 12 * * *', job);
```

The problem is that, when I initiate the server few minutes before the task should initiate, the job is being called only once as it should, if I initiate the server few hours before the 12pm, when 12pm reaches, the job is being called multiple times(around 4-6), does anyone encounter that before?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your parse-server with cluster module , because i faced the same issue , i had 4 cores so it was calling the job 4 times.

Comment: I don't even know what cluster module is, should I use it or in your case it was the cause of the problem?

Comment: If you were meaning NodeJS cluster module then no, is there something with Parse-server?